# java String to JSP as a href tag

Tags: java, jsp, hashmap

I need to get this

```
MMTUtil.getDomainDocumentationMap().get(documentationDTO.getId().getObjectName());
```

where .get(documentationDTO.getId().getObjectName()) is my key

using this will give me my String (value) which is a link
to be used in the jsp like this

```
<td><a href="" target="_blank"
id="domainName_<s:property value="#rowstatus.index"/>"><s:property
value="domainName" /></a></td>
```

so that the " " in href gets the String which i will be getting from the above code
and Unable to think of any solution
I have imported the class in the JSP thats how far I'm able to go

and this is my map

```
public class MMTUtil
{

private static Map<String, String> domainDocumentationMap = null;

static
{
    domainDocumentationMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
    domainComboDocumentationMap =new HashMap<String, String>();
}

public static Map<String, String> getDomainDocumentationMap() {
    return domainDocumentationMap;
}

public static void setDomainDocumentationMap(String objectName, String documentationLink) {
    MMTUtil.domainDocumentationMap.put(objectName, documentationLink);
}
```

okay I was able to do this in my jsp to atleast grab the objects from the package
like this

```
<%
UMRDocumentationDTO documentationDTO = new UMRDocumentationDTO();
String objectName = documentationDTO.getId().getObjectName();
String tc = MMTUtil.getDomainComboDocumentationMap().get(objectName);
%>
```

but it still need the outcome of the above last line in the href "tc"

```
<td><a href="tc" target="_blank"
id="domainName_<s:property value="#rowstatus.index"/>"><s:property
value="domainName" /></a></td>
```

Comment: `id="domainName_${rowstatus.index}">` or maybe `#{rowstatus.index}`

Comment: No this need not be changed , need to use that tc which is a link so that when I click on the "domainName" it takes me to the particular page